# query: get author of a song and count total of songs for that author

Tags: mysql, subquery

I'm not sure how to do the following query. I have 3 tables:

```
song (song_id, title, is_draft)
author (author_id, name)
song_author (song_id, author_id, display_order)
```

There are songs, and a song can have multiple authors and an author can write multiple songs

I want to output the authors of a specific song with the total numbers of songs that each author wrote.

So, if i pick **song_id**: **598**, i want to have a result set like this

```
author_id    name           total songs he wrote
------------------------------------------------
234          Michael Lord   58
589          Lama Turc      12
```

**NOTE:** The total number of songs each author wrote must exclude songs were **song.is_draft** equals 1 and **order** the result set by **song_author.displayorder**

From my research, i think i have to do 2 queries (sub queries) but that's as far as i got...

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT  author.author_id, author.name, count(song.song_id)
FROM song, author, song_author,
WHERE song.song_id = $id
AND song.song_id = song_author.song_id
AND song_author.author_id = author.author_id
AND song_author.display_order != 1
GROUP BY song_author.author_id, author.name
ORDER BY author.author_id asc;
```

Answer (score 0):

try this..

```
select b.author_Id, b.name, COUNT(a.Song_Id) as 'total'
FROm song_author as a
INNER JOIN author as b
    ON a.author_id = b.author_id
where a.song_id IN (select s.song_id
                    From songs as s
                    Where s.Song_Id = 598
                    AnD s.is_draft = 1)
GROUP bY b.author_Id, b.name
```

Comment: didn't see the last edit where you want is_draft = 1 and order by display order. please see updated answer.

Comment: tried it but i always get a 'total' of 1...and i know there are more

Comment: have u tried sub query by it self? did that give you satisfactory result?

Comment: still get 1 as the total number of songs

Comment: run it without where clause and see if  you get count higher than 1 on any rows.

Answer (score -1):

New to SQL too, but off the top of my head maybe this?  This doesn't explicitly spell out joins, but I've found it works for my purposes.  Maybe someone can let me know if this is bad practice?

```
Select author.author_id
, author.name
, count(author.author_id) 
from song, author, song_author     
where song.song_id = song_author.song_id 
and author.author_id = song_author.author_id 
group by author.authorid, author.name 
order by author.author_id asc;
```

Comment: this is older syntax - some people get all wrapped up on the newer explicit JOIN syntax - but fo rme, this works well.

Comment: Thanks- I'd ask if there is any real difference in performance compared to A INNER JOIN B ON A WHERE x = y INNTER JOIN B ON C WHERE y = z , but I'm sure I could just google it.  Interesting to know it's older

Comment: were are you picking the song_id ?